# UITextViewDelegate methods not being called (UITextView within UITableViewCell)

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I must be doing something fundamentally wrong, my implementation methods for the UITextViewDelegate aren't firing. I have a UITextView that is a subview of a UITableCellView and the delegates aren't being called.

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {

    NSLog(@"textViewDidBeginEditing");
    // never called...
}

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {

    NSLog(@"shouldChangeTextInRange");  
    // never called... 
}
```

Suggestions? I don't know whether it matters, but the protocol is explicitly named in my @interface declaration.

```
@interface DetailViewController () <UITextViewDelgate, ..., ....>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you actually set your view controller as the delegate of the text view? Something like `myTextView.delegate = myDetailViewController`...

Comment: I did NOT actually set my view controller as the delegate! THANK YOU!

Comment: @ToddB : Add following code in viewdidload
[noteTxtView.delegate self];

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should add the **textViewObj.delegate = self** or give delegate connection for that text view property in xib file, then it should work and fire all delegate methods of UITextView.

Comment: Amazing. I forgot to set the delegate. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 6):

Couple of pointers on this based on my experience:

1) Check whether you are using a UITextField or a UITextView.

2) Based on the type of text field you are using add the following declaration to your interface declaration

```
@interface MyInterface : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
                      or
@interface MyInterface : UIViewController<UITextViewDelegate>
```

3)Register your controller as the delegate for your text field:

```
[myTextField setDelegate:self];
```

4)Override the desired method which being

```
 -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
              or
 - (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView;
```

in my case.

Comment: Man you saved my life!!  I have been pulling my hair out trying to get this delegate to fire.   Then I read your comment 1) above.  It turns out that UITextField and UITextView look a lot alike when you have been chasing a bug for hours.